# Microsoft equivalent of the nm command

Tags: symbols, nm

I've long used cygwin's nm command for all my .lib symbol debugging needs, but recently I thought about referring to it in a SO answer and realized that most Windows developers don't have cygwin installed.

So what is the Microsoft equivalent to nm, i.e., what command will list the symbols exported by a .lib file, the undefined symbols in the .lib, and so forth?

For the curious, a sample nm man page is [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try dumpbin.exe.

[MSDN dumpbin.exe reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-170).

Comment: both links are dead :-(

Comment: yes, got it working. However, the MSDN documentation is next to worthless - a properly implemented `--help` argument could have superseeded it easily

Comment: Microsoft has three levels of support - primary support, advanced support, and technical support. These can be summed up with three phrases: 1) No one has ever reported an issue like that before; 2) Why would you ever want to do that?; and 3) I'm-pissed-I've-got-to-talk-to-actual-users-so-I'm-going-to-talk-real-fast-and-spout-code-like-a-fountain-and-you'd-better-get-it-all-down-the-first-time-because-I-will-NOT-repeat-myself.

Answer (score 7):

1. Run `vcvarsall.bat` which might present in your installed path of Microsoft Visual Studio. This sets environmental variable required for `dumpbin.exe`.

   `D:>"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\vcvarsall.bat" x86`
2. Then use `dumpbin.exe`. For example `dumpbin.exe /ALL <bin_file>` gives all symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The `nm` command provides `-C` option, which shows demangled names.
There is `c++filt` in Linux/MacOSX, provide nearly the same as `-C` for nm.

On Windows, there is dumpbin.exe, which is like `nm` on Linux.
There is also `undname` on Windows, which is like `c++filt` on Linux:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-170)

```
C:\>undname ?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z"
is :- "private: void __thiscall a::func1(int)"
```

You may also need [vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) to locate where `dumpbin.exe` and `undname.exe` located.