# Is there a replacement for nm on Windows?

Tags: windows, nm

I would like to examine object files on Windows similar to the Linux tool **nm**. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft equivalent of the nm command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375273/microsoft-equivalent-of-the-nm-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft equivalent of the nm command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375273/microsoft-equivalent-of-the-nm-command)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try 'DUMPBIN'. You can see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) the description of this tool and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the reference.

In addition, a GUI is available [here](http://www.cheztabor.com/dumpbinGUI/index.htm).

[image]

Comment: it MUST be NM not an other tool

Comment: @SandroMunda it might not be what the OP was hoping for but it's definitely a good solution when you need to examine the method signature coming out of a c++ binary object - thanks