# include id3lib in QT project, C++

Tags: c++, qt, mp3, qt5, id3lib

==================================

Configuration :

- Qt Creator 2.8.1
- Qt 5.1.1
- Windows 7 64 bits

==================================

How can I include id3lib library ?

I've already donwloaded required files (.h, .dll, .lib and .exp) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3lib/files/

I've already included all .h file in my project :

```
HEADERS  += audioTest.h \
    id3.h \
    id3/writers.h \
    id3/writer.h \
    id3/utils.h \
    id3/tag.h \
    id3/sized_types.h \
    id3/readers.h \
    id3/reader.h \
    id3/misc_support.h \
    id3/io_strings.h \
    id3/io_helpers.h \
    id3/io_decorators.h \
    id3/id3lib_strings.h \
    id3/id3lib_streams.h \
    id3/id3lib_frame.h \
    id3/helpers.h \
    id3/globals.h \
    id3/field.h
```

Then I've included the library :

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/id3lib/ -lid3lib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/id3lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/id3lib
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/id3lib/id3lib.lib
```

Then, when I execute the bellow example, it tells me

- `undefined reference to ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const*)'`
- `undefined reference to 'ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag()'`
- `error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Code :

```
ID3_Tag tag("a.mp3");
```

Something wrong with what I've done ? I know `undefined reference to *` means a bad library inclusion, but I can't find where I failed.

And I can't find solution on the web :

- [Here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29946-compiling-id3lib-on-windows-Qt) they decide to use `taglib`, but I read [here](http://thefrogprince.tripod.com/id3lib-detail.htm) id3lib was better.
- [Here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/including-id3lib-523477/) they say `LIBS += /usr/lib/libid3.a` works. But not on Windows.
- ...

Someone got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems ongoing...

First of all, you do not need to include 3rd party headers into your `HEADERS` variable. You only need to specify the location for the `INCLUDEPATH` if any.

Secondly, you will need to specify the library name *and* location for the `LIBS` variable as follows:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/id3lib/installation -lid3libname
```

Comment: But id3lib is not delivered with sources file... Just .h, .lib, .dll and .a... Or I don't understand what you mean by including sources file

Comment: @LetAurn: you need to import the _source_ of the 3rd party project into your project. If it is header only, you definitely should not link against it which you seem to be doing.

Comment: So you are telling me to include some headers only ?

Comment: Ok, I removed all id3lib headers from `HEADERS` and I did thid :
`LIBS += -L$$PWD/id3/ -lid3lib`
`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/id3`
But still doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work : same problem. `undefined reference to ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const*)'`, `undefined reference to ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag()'`

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is because I use MinGW. No ?

Comment: Pardon? The very beginning of your question states: "Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bits)". Please do not trick us. :)

Comment: :D it was in "About Qt Creator" dialog, sorry.
I didn't notice the `g++ -c -pipe XXX` in logs.

Comment: As requested already, check whether the symbols are actually available... although, if you have symbols stripped, you will not be lucky.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an equivalent of `nm` command on Windows.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375273/microsoft-equivalent-of-the-nm-command

Comment: I do not need the output. :) It is you who should check it. I cannot really do much more on top of it.

Comment: humm... how ? I got this result, how can I check it now ?
wait, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib

Comment: @LetAurn: have you resolved the nitty-gritty details?

Comment: No, I decided to use `TagLib 1.9-1`, which I recompiled to run it succesfully. That made me think that the pre-compiled version of id3lib was not supported by my gcc version. I am pretty sure it was my problem.

Comment: @LetAurn: OK, in that case, if you do not wish to fix the issue, I will vote on your question to be closed unfortunately because we cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile? I have Linux and compile with g++ -lid3 -lz. Switch -lid3 is for id3lib which needs compress as well so -lz.

Comment: @Frits I don't think that you understand this topic. Are you sure you know id3lib?