# Is is possible to verify the linked functions that a dll is using through static library using dependency walker?

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, static-libraries, dependency-walker

I am creating a dll that is using a static library. My problem is, when I am using this dll in a test application, I am getting the linking error for the function that is called from my dll. This function is defined in static library.

I am using this set up,

```
abc.lib  ---->  xyz.dll  ----> test_application
```

This test application is getting linking error for the function that is called from one of the exposed function from dll.

Now I wanted to verify whether I have properly compiled my dll with static library or not? I am using dependency walker, will it show any useful information or not? If not, any other useful tool for it.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? I'm pretty sure a dependency walker won't show a problem, but I'd git it a try, since it's an easy thing to do.

Comment: Hi Mats, I am getting a linking error for from xyz.dll for calling a function from abc.lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nm command or elf utility we can understand the way the symbols are linked and being resolved. Broadly speaking there are 2 types of symbols based on the linkages, Weak & Strong.

More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

Windows Equivalent of elf or nm commands:- [Microsoft equivalent of the nm command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375273/microsoft-equivalent-of-the-nm-command)