# How to find which functions are in a static c/c++ library in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, static-libraries

I have an application, and a static library. The library appears to build just fine - it certainly compiles my `foo` and `bar` and `geewhizz` functions just fine, and creates the static library without any errors or warnings.

However, when the application builds and links to the static library, it manages to link to functions `foo` and `bar` but cannot find function `geewhizz`. How can I tell if `geewhizz` made it into the library? I can't see any `/map` option for libraries like there is for building the applications. And it is pointless using the `\map` option when building the application, because it can't find my `geewhizz` function, and has no basis to report on it.

I am working with a mixture of C and C++, and I suspect there is probably a function name mangling/translation issue, or calling convention issue, that is causing the problem, so I think having a list of the functions included in the library should be able to shine light on that. But if there is any more general advice for resolving such issues, I'd be pleased to hear it.

Comment: so you get a linking error, right?

Comment: @MarcoA.: Only when linking an executable against the shared library.  He wants to know if his shared library is valid _before_ he tries to use it.

Comment: @MarcoA: Not any more - I have since fixed my link error by declaring `geewhizz` inside an `extern "C" {...}` construct. But I'm still interested to know how to get a listing of functions in a static library, because this would have helped confirm my suspicion a lot quicker. The static libary was always valid

Comment: You can try dumpbin.exe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375273/microsoft-equivalent-of-the-nm-command.  I don't know whether it works on static libraries but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: @indiv - great answer - it does work on static libraries - but really really really cryptic. nm command?!?!? You really have to be an insider to know what that is.

Comment: @WhozCraig - in light of the above, maybe you should mark that other answer as a duplicate of this one ;-) I think someone should spell out the `dumpbin /linkermember` syntax and gain a few free rep points as grateful people upvote both question and answer

Comment: `lib.exe` will likely also get at least some info, specifically the /list option. It will at least list the obis.

Comment: @omatai:  Glad it helped.  If you'd like, you can be that someone and answer your own question.  I won't leave an answer because I lack the environment to experiment for a quality answer.  (I just knew that `nm` would do what you wanted on Linux and googled it)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to helpful comments from @indiv and @WhozCraig in particular, you have at least these two options:

- Use the `/LIST` option in Visual Studio's linker program (`lib.exe`)
- Use the `dumpbin` utility with the `/linkermember` option

Visual studio is not exactly helpful in making the `/LIST` option easy to use. You will have to specify it as an additional option on the Command Line, but how to do that is not clear. `/LIST` on its own produces a listing to standard output, but neither specifying a file nor using the `>` redirection operator work in any obvious way. In fact, I've given up trying to work out how to make this option work at all.

Thankfully, `dumpbin` is a utility shipped with Visual Studio (even the Express versions) and is well documented [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429). So until someone makes `/LIST` remotely workable to ordinary people, use `dumpbin`.